# Check or uncheck the parent parents check box using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

When I checked **Account Settings** checkbox all children li input tags are checked perfectly. but when I unchecked Children li checkbox **Add** and **Delete** it's unchecking **Account Settings** too.

I don't want to uncheck **Account Settings** when **AS One** and **AS Two** is checked.

Help me out, how to solve this.

Here [Jsfiidle](https://jsfiddle.net/siddhuphp/e32zcp5k/)

below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tree" id="tree">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="account_settings" value="yes">Account Settings
        <!-- AND SHOULD CHECK HERE -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="one">AS One</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="two" value="two">AS Two</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="user_roles" value="user_roles">Users &amp; Roles
                <!-- SHOULD CHECK HERE -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="user_role" value="add">Add</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="user_role" value="delete">Delete</li>
                    <!-- CHECK HERE -->
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rl_module" value="yes">RL Module</li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rl_module" value="yes">Accounting
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="vat" value="yes">VAT</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="bank_account" value="yes">Banking
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="view" value="yes">View</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="crud" value="yes">CRUD</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    var sibs = false;
    $(this).closest('ul').children('li').each(function () {
           if($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) sibs=true;
    })
    $(this).parents('ul').prev().prop('checked', sibs);
});
```

Comment: You have use only html tags. Please use it's id or name to differentiate the checkbox..

Comment: Yes, It should dynamic in my side. so i used tags

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see that.

Comment: It's pritty good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul class="tree" id="tree">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="account_settings" value="yes">Account Settings
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input class="account_settings" type="checkbox" name="one" value="one">AS One
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="account_settings" type="checkbox" name="two" value="two">AS Two
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="account_settings" type="checkbox" name="user_roles" value="user_roles">Users &amp; Roles
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input class="account_settings user_roles" type="checkbox" name="user_role" value="add">Add
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input class="account_settings user_roles" type="checkbox" name="user_role" value="delete">Delete
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        $('.'+$(this).attr('name')).prop('checked',true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('.'+$(this).attr('name')).prop('checked',false);
    }
    findparent(this);
});
});

function findparent(elem)
{
    var flag = 1;
    var fcount = 0;
    var count = 0;
    $(elem).parent().parent().find('li input').each( function ( index ) {
        fcount = fcount +1;
        if($(this).prop('checked') == false)
            count = count + 1;
    });

    if(count == fcount)
        flag = 0;

    if(flag == 0)
        $(elem).parent().parent().prev().prop('checked',false);
    else
        $(elem).parent().parent().prev().prop('checked',true);
}
```

Comment: It's working fine. when I uncheck Add and Delete   Users & Roles is still show checked. how can I uncheck the parent Users & Roles

Comment: Please check the code again. I have updated it. Added another function to check the parent checkbox and sibling checkboxes.

Comment: Perfect. But in my case, it should be repeated nested checkboxes number of times. once check this url  https://jsfiddle.net/siddhuphp/e32zcp5k/2/

Comment: Checked your url. What i mean is, give the value of name attribute of current checkbox as the class name of the children checkboxes. This is applicable to all checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn;t get you. Can you show me in jsfiddle ?

Comment: What i have given in my example is the child checkbox's class name is the name attribute of the parent check box. For the 'Add' and 'Delete' check box the class name are 'account_settings user_roles'. Because these check boxes are the children of both check boxes having the name attribute as 'account_settings' and 'user_roles'. You must arrange the class name of the child check box depending upon the parent check box.  I hope u understand my example.